# Material-UI DataGrid autoPageSize property not honored on component mount

Tags: material-ui

I have a Material-UI DataGrid with the autoPageSize property set. When the component renders with the "Rows per page" dropdown and shows that rows 1-100 of 100 are visible. Once I click the "Rows per page" dropdown, it disappears and it correctly shows that rows 1-10 of 100 are visible.

This is the code for my DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} autoPageSize pagination/>
```

[On initial load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OV9Lu.png)

[After clicking the "Rows per page" dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNDzI.png)

How do I make it so the DataGrid shows the correct number of visible rows on the initial render instead of after having to click the "Rows per page" dropdown?

Comment: The documentation states that the default page size is 100, which is what you are seeing. you can change this by setting the  `pageSize={10}` prop for example. Without seeing the code ini your TS file it's difficult, but an appropriate place to set it would be in the ngOnInit section.

Comment: Why is it using the default page size when autoPageSize should be calculating the page size based on the parent components height?